# Bluemix: download starter code option unavailable

Tags: download, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

In the last week I created a simple application in Bluemix. Afterwards, I was able to press the "Start Coding" hyperlink in the dashboard. This took me to a screen which had a button to "Download Starter Code". When I pressed this button, I downloaded the source code in a zip file. Now, however, when I try to press the button to "Start Coding", I no longer have an option to "Download Starter Code". I only have the option to "Download CF Command Line Interface". Was this capability taken away because I already downloaded the code before? I don't think this is true because I created an application today and then downloaded the starter code. Afterwards, I pressed the "Start Coding" button and came to a screen which still had the "Download Starter Code" button.

Comment: Are you trying to use a certain boilplate?  Where exactly are you in the catalog?

Comment: @RandalAnders I am in the dashboard under applications. I have two applications. The one I created today I can download the starter code for. The one I created a few days ago I cannot. Both applications use a runtime of "SDK for Node.js". The application I cannot download starter code for is bound to "Cloudant NoSQL DB". The one I can download starter code for is bound to "Cloudant NoSQL DB" and "Monitoring and Analytics".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application was created using one of the "boilerplates" then you should still have the option to download your starter code as seen below:

[image]

However, if you initially pushed your application to bluemix via CF, then you will see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the starter code link is removed once you push your one the first time.
Which runtime are/were you using?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps properly, I used the tutorials from the Bluemix:  https://hub.jazz.net/tutorials/

Hope this will help you!